# C# threads and backgroundworker problem

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my main thread I run Backgroundworker. His todo work is method that Invoke "Method" from main thread. When I wish to cancel my backgroundworker it stops running but "Method" invoked on mainthread still run what cause problems. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Post some code that demonstrate the issue you have.

Comment: Please, will you provide some sample code or an extended explanation?

Comment: could you show some code for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides checking for `CancellationPending`, you need set the `Cancel` property on the `DoWorkEventArgs` argument.

Then, in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, you can query the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`'s `Cancelled` property that will reflect the value you set in `DoWorkEventArgs`.

Now you may ask why the `BackgroundWorker` does not set these properties by itself whenever the operation is cancelled externally. The reason is that it does not know if your DoWorkEventArgs actually checked if it was cancelled. `DoWorkEventArgs` could have missed it and completed successfully. This is important because it could have caused side effects (like a database update) and you may need to know if it was actually done or not.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) notes that you must check for [`CancellationPending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) inside `Method` (do you do that?)